# Remove metabox from custom post editor

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, meta-boxes

I've created a custom post type with a main metabox and two custom taxonomies in my `functions.php`. To create the taxonomies I used `register_taxonomy()`.

In the custom post's main metabox, I manage my taxonomies, i.e. I tick some checkboxes. So I don't need the side-bar metaboxes anymore, I want to get rid of them, just as if I had their names unticked in the screen options.

Still, I want the taxonomies to appear in the left admin panel, associated to the custom post type I've created.

I tried `remove_meta_box()` but it has no effect. I tried to play with `show_ui` and `show_in_menu` : if the former is set to true and the latter to false, I have the metaboxes but the taxonomies disappear from my admin sidebar, so it is exactly the opposite of I want to do !

How can this be solved ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently, and found that `remove_meta_box()` worked, but it had to be hooked by the `admin_menu` action.

For example:

```
add_action('admin_menu',  'cs49323_update_meta_boxes');

function cs49323_update_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY', YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE, 'side' );
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. It took a while to find the correct answer as the official docs are wrong, and lots of SO answers have the incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I misformed the target metabox to hide. The `div` tag must be contatenated to the name of the metabox, after it :

```
function remove_my_meta() {
remove_meta_box( 'mymetadiv','mycustompost','side' );
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_my_meta');
```

where `mycustompost` is the custom post type, and `mymeta` is the custom taxonomy.